# How to get data from a table to state

Tags: reactjs, html-table, state

I'm trying to build a table that as soon as you click it, state will be updated with the information from the table, but I don't know how to do that

This is my code:

```
state = {
    shift: {
      id: '',
      shift: '',
      date: ''
    },
    days: [
      'Sunday',
      'Monday',
      'Tuesday',
      'Wednesday',
      'Thursday',
      'Friday',
      'Saturday'
    ],
    shifts: ['Morning', 'Evening']
  };
  render() {
    const table = this.state.shifts.map((shift, index) => {
      return (
        <tr key={index}>
          {this.state.days.map((day, index2) => {
            return (
              <td key={index2}>
                <div>{day}</div>
                <div>{shift}</div>
                <div>
                  <button>Sign in</button>
                </div>
              </td>
            );
          })}
        </tr>
      );
    });
```

I want to write a function onClick that as soon as I click the button I want the `this.state.shift` to be updated with the morning/evening that the TD contains it , and same for `this.state.date` to be added with the day Sunday/Monday...  does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `<td>` you can put

`onClick={event => this.setState({shift: {id: '', shift, date: day})}`
Put whatever you want the `id` to be, and `shift` is just a destructured object.

I'm assuming you were referring to `this.state.shift.shift` and `this.state.shift.date`.